# Understanding the derivative of inverse function.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, inverse-function

I'm puzzled with the statement of differential of inverse function.

Let $f: X\to Y$ be a differentiable function.

If there exists $g:Y\to X$ s.t. $y=f(x) \Leftrightarrow x=g(y)$, then $g$ is called the inverse function of $f$.

And then, $\dfrac{dg(y)}{dy}=\dfrac{1}{\frac{df(x)}{dx}}$ holds.

I understand the statement above, but in another literature, the statement is a bit different. The statement is below.

Let $y=f(x)$ be differentiable.

If there exists the inverse function $y=g(x)$, then $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{1}{\frac{dx}{dy}} \ \cdots (\ast)$ holds.

I'm puzzled by this statement.

This mentions that $y=g(x)$ is inverse of $y=f(x)$, but if we write so, $f(x)=y=g(x)$ would hold but of course this doesn't hold. I cannot understand why this replaces $x=g(y)$ with $y=g(x)$.

And in $(\ast),$ I think the LHS  means $\dfrac{dg(x)}{dx}$ but what does $\dfrac{dx}{dy}$ in the RHS mean ? Perhaps $\dfrac{dx}{dy}$ may mean $\dfrac{dg(y)}{dy}$ but the statement doesn't describes $x=g(y)$.

I'm confused. I'd like you to give me any help to understand this.

Answer (score 1):

If $y=f(x)$ and $x=g(t)$, then the first derivative:

$\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{df}{dx}\frac{dg}{dt}$.

If the inverse function of $y=f(x)$ is $x=g(y)$, then $t=y$ and

$\frac{dy}{dy}=\frac{df}{dx}\frac{dg}{dy}=1$,

$\frac{dg}{dy}=\frac{1}{\frac{df}{dx}}$.